# Tracking mouse events on scrollbar

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a component that is sub-classed to a dialog and I am handling mouse events within the component. What I'm trying to achieve is changing **visibility of scrollbar** depending on the mouse events (i.e. the scrollbar appears only when the mouse hovers the area). I am handling `TrackMouseEvent` on `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message, and using `ShowScrollBar` on `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` repectively.

It works as expected except when a mouse hovers the scrollbar. It sends both `WM_MOUSEHOVER` and `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages constantly, and the whole area blinks like it gets redrawn every second.

I am not so sure about the behavior of `ShowScrollbar` along with the `TrackMouseEvent`. Can anyone help me find a way to crack this problem?

My app is developed under Win32 without MFC, and here is little snippet of my code.

```
// gets called once on initialize
void CUDComment::InitScrollRange(int cyWindow)
{
    int nTotal = _getTotalItemHeight();
    int nRangeY = nTotal - cyWindow + _getItemHeight();
    if( nRangeY < 0 ) nRangeY = 0;

    if( m_nVerPos >= nRangeY )
    {
        m_nVerPos = nRangeY;
    }

    DWORD dwScrollState = 0;
    // Hide scrollbar when the content is just one line
    if( nTotal > cyWindow )
    {
        dwScrollState = 1;
        m_bShowScroll = TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        if( m_bShowScroll )
        {
            dwScrollState = 2;
            m_bShowScroll = FALSE;
        }
    }

    if( dwScrollState > 0 )
    {
        SCROLLINFO siVer;

        siVer.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);
        siVer.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
        siVer.nMin = 0;

        if( dwScrollState == 2 )
        {
            siVer.nMax = 0;
            siVer.nPage = 0;
            siVer.nPos = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            siVer.nMax = nRangeY;
            siVer.nPage = min(nRangeY, (int)_getItemHeight());
            siVer.nPos = m_nVerPos;
        }

        SetScrollInfo(m_hWnd, SB_VERT, &siVer, TRUE);
    }
}

void CUDComment::OnMouseMove(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if( !m_bTracking )
    {
        TRACKMOUSEEVENT tme;

        tme.cbSize = sizeof(tme);
        tme.hwndTrack = m_hWnd;
        tme.dwFlags = TME_LEAVE | TME_HOVER;
        tme.dwHoverTime = 500;

        m_bTracking = TrackMouseEvent(&tme);
    }
}

void CUDComment::OnMouseHover(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    ShowScrollBar(m_hWnd, SB_VERT, TRUE);
}

void CUDComment::OnMouseLeave(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    m_bTracking = FALSE;
    ShowScrollBar(m_hWnd, SB_VERT, FALSE);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that when you show the scrollbar, the region which used to be part of the client area becomes part of the non-client area, and so the `TME_LEAVE` tracking is triggered. Rather than setting both leave and hover tracking at the same time, I think you should set leave tracking only when the scrollbar is shown (and use the `TME_NONCLIENT` flag to track it in the non-client area). Then when you hide the scrollbar again, reestablish the hover tracking.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Right. That's what I've thought about the reason behind the unexpected behavior. But it does not really click in my mind about how it's consistently sending both messages, not just `WM_MOUSELEAVE` once. But anyhow, thanks for the hint. I will try that right away.

Comment: Hi, @vaska11 did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I tried Johnathan's method, but it did not quite work when I set `TME_LEAVE` and `TME_NONCLIENT` trigger for `TrackMouseEvent`. I could not get the mouse to capture the nonclient area. What I did was to basically **calculate the size of the scrollbar**(`GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVSCROLL)`) **and its coordinates**, and then ignore the leave message when my mouse hovers the scrollbar area. So I basically created an exception case while handling my `WM_MOUSELEAVE`message.

Overall codes look similar except my `OnMouseLeave` function.

```
void CUDComment::OnMouseLeave(HWND hWnd, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    POINT ptCurrent;

    GetCursorPos(&ptCurrent);
    ScreenToClient(hWnd, &ptCurrent);

    if (!PtInRect(&m_rcScrollbar, ptCurrent))
    {
        ShowScrollBar(hWnd, SB_VERT, FALSE);
        m_bTracking = FALSE;
    }

}
```